# Fastest way to flush a hashmap to disk into an sorted set

Tags: java, list, sorting, queue, hashmap

I have a `Map<byte[], Element>` and I want to sort it and write it to disk, so that I have a file with all the elements sorted by key through Guava's `UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator`.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
HashMap<byte[], Element> memory;

// ... code creating and populating memory ...

TreeMap<byte[], Element> sortedMap = new TreeMap<byte[], Element>(UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator());
sortedMap.putAll(memory.getMap());

MyWriter writer = new MyWriter("myfile.dat");
for (Element element: sortedMap.values())
    writer.write(element);
writer.close();
```

It's probably difficult to make the sorting faster (O(nlogn)), the question is whether I can improve on the navigation of the sorted list. Ideally I'd sort into an `ArrayList` instead of a `TreeMap`, so that iterating through it would be very fast.

I thought about putting the HashMap into an `ArrayList` and `Collections.sort()` it, but that would require more copying than the actual solution.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I add here my test with `ArrayList` which is 2x faster, but I assume it uses more memory. Maybe some comments on this assumption?

```
// ArrayList-based implementation 2x faster
ArrayList<Element> sorted = new ArrayList<Element>(memory.size());
sorted.addAll(memory.values());

final Comparator<byte[]> lexic = UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator();

Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<Element>(){
    public int compare(Element arg0, Element arg1) {
        return lexic.compare(arg0.getKey(), arg1.getKey());
    }
});
MyWriter writer = new MyWriter(filename);

for (Element element: sorted)
    writer.write(element);
writer.close();
```

Comment: The main thing you need to improve is the writing to disk.  This can be 100x slow than anything else you do.  I would use a profiler to check where you are spending your time.

Comment: there's little improvement there, I'm already using DataOutputStream with Buffering, it's easy sequential approach. As my microbenchmark shows, sorting and iterating make a difference.

Comment: Why do you say making an ArrayList<Pair<byte[], Element>> (for instance) and sorting it requires more 'copying' than constructing a TreeMap?

Comment: "The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance. This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place." So the elements are copied to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was "Any ideas?". I guess anything I could write would be an answer.

I had the same problem as you, and extensively benchmarked the two solutions: use a treemap so items were sorted in advance, or sort them after the fact. My benchmark showed the same result as yours. It's faster to sort after the fact.

I wouldn't be concerned about the fact that the second approach requires more copying. First, faster is faster, right? If the second approach takes fewer CPU cycles then it's better.

If memory is a concern, then keep in mind that treemaps and hashmaps take far more memory per item than an ArrayList, which is backed by a simple object array. Each element in a treemap or hashmap requires at least one object, and usually more. Objects have a lot of overhead, 32 or more bytes. In a flat array each element takes only 4 bytes.

My benchmarks showed that the time to allocate an array from memory was roughly proportional to the size of the array, once you got to an array size over a few dozen bytes. So allocating the ArrayList may be slow if it's really large. Still, I think it's the better bet, so long as there's no danger of running out of memory.

Comment: actually, i was checking memory consumption with visualvm and the treemap implementation uses more memory. I guess as i have about 5 million elements, that makes about 20MB for the array. That is very much ok with me. Thanks for you insight!